# How can a quadratic minimization problem of this form be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider the quadratic minimization problem of the form :

Finding a vector $x$ that minimizes :
$$
\|Ax-b\|_{2}^{2}+\|Bx-c\|_{2}^{2}
$$
I am familiar with ordinary least squares problem but this is the first time I encounter such type of least square problems.

I know that by the properties of vector norms, we can bound this expression from below since for any two vectors $u$ and $v$ we know $\|u+v\|_{2}<\|u\|_{2}+\|v\|_{2}$

I would hope for some urgent help.

Comment: alright, thank you very much! would an SVD be best to solve this? or does QR have better closed form? @MichaelHoppe

Comment: Hint: the gradient is $$(A^TA+B^TB)x-(A^Tb+B^Tc),$$ hence $$x= (A^TA+B^TB)^{-1}(A^Tb+B^Tc).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\|Ax-b\|_{2}^{2}+\|Bx-c\|_{2}^{2} = 
\left\| \begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}x - \begin{bmatrix}b\\c\end{bmatrix} \right\|_2^2$$
So this is again a classic least square problem

Comment: would you recommend using SVD to solve this type of LSP because it seems that we have a matrix embedding $A$ and $B$ together.